# Relacionar un usuario a un estudio y una carrera

Tags: sql-server, relaciones, arquitectura, arquitectura-de-software

Estoy tratando de realizar un modelo que pueda realizar lo siguiente. Un usuario puede tener un estudio realizado (estos estan codificados 1-Primerio 2-Secundario 3-Universitario). Y si el estudio es Universitario (3) debo pedir el nombre de la carrera.

Yo pense algo asi pero no funciona y mas abajo explico por que.

Usuarios

- UsuarioID
- Nombre
- EstudioID (clave foreanea a Estudios, que permite un usuario tener un estudio y a los estudios tener muchos usuarios)

Estudios

- EstudioID
- Nombre

Carrera

- CarreraID
- Nombre
- EstudioID (clave foreanea a Estudios, que permite a una carrera tener un estudio y a un estudio tener muchas carreras).

Eso creo que estaria bien, pero no se si hago asi, como obtener que carrera hizo un usuario dando como parametro el Id de este.

Alguien me ayudaria? Gracias.

Comment: Hola, y si relaciones la tabla usuario a las otras dos tablas ? , estas relacionando estudio a las demás deberías de relacionar el usuario a estudio y carrera

Comment: Y que pasa si un usuario estudia muchas carreras? Una solucion a ello seria crear una tabla que contenga solo el id usuario y el id carrera, de esta forma puedes obtener la info que necesitas mediante **JOINS**

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera tienes razon deberias tener una tabla intermedia

Comment: Gracias @PauloUrbanoRivera. Puse que iba a comentar por que no funcionaba y al final me olvide. Uno de los problemas era el que comentas. Entonces me recomiendas que haga una tabla ej: UsuariosCarreras, que tenga como propiedades -id -UsuarioID -CarreraID? Y que seria eso de JOINS, estoy empezando a hacer cosas "mas complicadas" con bases de datos y no se mucho todavia

Comment: Gracias @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO por la respuesta. Habia pensado la forma que me dijiste pero me seguia causando problemas

Comment: @iMSn20 claro, la tabla que indicas esta perfecto... ahora en cuanto a los JOINS es una caracteristica de SQL que te permite, mediante algun campo de tu tabla concordante con otro de N tablas extraer la informacion que necesitas. Te dejo un [link](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Fundamentos-de-SQL-Consultas-SELECT-multi-tabla-Tipos-de-JOIN.aspx) para que te quede mas claro.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera, hice esta tabla:
UsuarioEstudio que tiene -id -UsuarioID -EstudioID -CarreraID, entonces cuando un usuario se va a registrar, y se le pide por sus estudios, si tiene un EstudioID que sea el de Universitario, va a pedirle la carrera que realizo, y esta se registrara con un CarreraID en la tabla Carreras y a su vez se agregara al registro anterior poniendo el id que se acaba de generar. Por lo cual si busco en la tabla UsuariosEstudios, podre obtener por un determinado usuario los estudios que tiene y si es universitario que carrera es.

Comment: Yo sacaria el estudioId, ya que por defecto si ingresas una carrera estas indicando que es Universitario

Comment: Si, pero un usuario puede haber hecho solamente la secundaria o la primeria. Creo que ahora si lo tengo solucionado y es de esta forma:
Usuarios: -UsuarioID -Nombre -EstudioID;

Estudios: -EstudioID -Nombre;

Carreras: -CarreraID -Nombre;

Usuarios/Carreras: -UCID -UsuarioID -CarreraID

Entonces si solicito el usuario con ID-> 1 tiene codigo estudio 3, quiere decir que tiene al menos un estudio universitario, y voy a la tabla Usuarios/Carreras y solicito todos los registros de ese UsuarioID y me devuelve tambien los CarrerasID y con eso en Carreras busco los nombres de estas. @PauloUrbanoRiver